# Ethernet port on Zero and A+?

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, ethernet-port, connectors, pi-a+

The Pi Zero and A+ both have what seems like space for an ethernet port on the bottom, in the section labeled `J5`:

[image: A+][image: Zero]

Is this really an ethernet port, and if so, how would one connect to it (provide links to a jack that would fit)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an ethernet port, it's a JTAG port for debugging.

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't look like JTAG.

Comment: Look at the signal names, TRST, TDI, TDO, TMS...

Comment: @Gusman Well, shouldn't JTAG have 6 pins (including GND)?

Comment: @Gusman Those are the JTAG signals. What about them?

Comment: No, 6, http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_Connector_JTAG_Bus.html TRST, TDI, TDO, TMS, TCK and GND, lok at the pins, there are two grounds and one unused pin, in total eight pins

Comment: @Coder256 Then that port is a JTAG port

Comment: Here is the full description on that port: http://www.sheffieldhardwarehackers.org.uk/wordpress/2015/12/the-hunt-for-j5/

Answer (score 3):

No it's not an ethernet port (and it doesn't look anything like one either).

It's the videocore JTAG port, that connector is used on all Pi models since the B+ (the original raspberry pi model A and B use a pin header instead). It is used by the engineers who developed the Pi for debugging.

Unfortunately it's not much use unless you have access to broadcom information and tools that are not available to the public.